# Run UPDATE Statement for row with TICKED Checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table writing a list of OrderID's and the Dates of the Order.

```
<table border="1" style="margin: 10px 0;">
    <form action="code/update-to-dispatched.php" method="post" name="markAsDispatched">
        <?php
            foreach ($orders as $row) {
                echo "<tr class='even'>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<strong>Order Date:</strong> ". $row['OrderDate'] ." <br />";
                echo "</td>";                   
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<strong>Order ID:</strong> ". $row['OrderID'] ."";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkBox' value='1'>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>

        <span class="tag"><a href="javascript:checkall('markAsDispatched','chkBox',true)">CHECK ALL</a></span>
        <span class="tag"><a href="javascript:checkall('markAsDispatched','chkBox',false)">UNCHECK ALL</a></span>
        <input type="submit" name="markAsDispatched" value="MARK AS DISPATCHED" />
    </form>
</table>
```

How can I run an UPDATE Statement on code/update-to-dispatched.php, to UPDATE the Status of the Order to Dispatched (if the checkbox is ticked), from Success? Here is what I have already.

```
<?php
    $servername = "REMOVED";
    $username = "REMOVED";
    $password = "REMOVED";
    $dbname = "REMOVED;
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);

    try {
        if(isset($_POST['chkBox'])) {
            $stmt = "UPDATE orders SET Status = :status WHERE OrderID IN (". $_POST['chkBox'] .")";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);
            $stmt->execute(array(':status' => "Dispatched"));
            header('Location: /cms/mark-orders-dispatched.php');
        }

        else {
            echo "NO UPDATE";
        }       
    }   

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;               
?>
```

Comment: forget to close  quotes `$dbname = "REMOVED";`

Comment: Do not use `$_POST` values directly in SQL statement, which may result in SQL Injection attacks. By the way, it's a good habit to add an `exit();` after `header('Location: ')` to prevent unwanted codes to be executed.

Comment: I have added exit(); to my header('Location: '). Also, I usually include config.php, which contains a connection. Would you do... $servername = "name"; or $servername = "$ServerName"; in terms of security? @Raptor

Comment: You can't really avoid using `$servername= "name";` in config file; there must be a place storing these settings. As long as your DB is not exposed directly to public (usually it's behind firewall, with port 3306 only available by local connection), you'll be fine...

Answer (score 0):

At very first , render checkboxes in such a way so that you can fetch them in array whose having order ids.

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkBox[]' value='$row['OrderID']'>";
```

Now run your query for each checked checkboxes ,as

```
$ids=$_POST['chkBox'];
foreach($ids as $id)
{
$stmt = "UPDATE orders SET Status = :status WHERE OrderID=$id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);
$stmt->execute(array(':status' => "Dispatched"));
}
header('Location: /cms/mark-orders-dispatched.php');
```

OR SIMPLY 
Run your query without loop as

```
 $ids=$_POST['chkBox'];
 $stmt = "UPDATE orders SET Status = :status WHERE OrderID In ".implode(",",$ids);
```

Comment: Hey, watch out SQL Injection !